# Filtering an IList

Tags: c#, linq, list, delegates

In my application this code works (populates tasks with expected results) for getting all tasks where the parent is null AKA rootTasks:

```
IList<Task> tasks = ObjectSpace.GetObjects<Task>();

var rootTasks = tasks.ToList().FindAll(delegate (Task t) { return t.Parent == null; });
```

but this does not (rootTasks is empty in this case):

```
var rootTasks = tasks.Where(x => x.Parent == null);
```

Can someone please show me the correct way to do this using the .Where?

Also any comments as to why I should use one vs the other are welcome.

Comment: "but this does not" doesn't describe the problem at all. What goes wrong with the code that doesn't work? It looks fine to me...

Comment: Is it a matter of you not calling `.ToList()` on the `Where` ?

Comment: added better description for "works"

Comment: `Where` should never return `null`.

Comment: you're right it's not null it's empty

Comment: Please read [ask] and create a [mcve]. The code you show does not reproduce the issue you claim.

Comment: does `tasks` list consists of same set of objects in all cases?

Comment: One thing that is funny is people posting questions then providing answers to their own questions based upon someone else's comments and then mark them as answers. The author of the post should not be able to post an answer himself.

Comment: When you say "`rootTasks` is empty in this case`" what do you mean? How did you determine that? You should show all the code that shows the issue you're experiencing.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to say more about what isn't working. Do you see an error message? If so, what is it? It is not producing the expected output? If not, what output do you see and what output do you expect?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

.ToList() is required at the end like this:

```
var rootTasks = tasks.Where(x => x.Parent == null).ToList();
```

Comment: `ToList` should not be required. `Where` returns a lazy sequence so you need to iterate over it to evaluate the query but you don't need to use `ToList` to do it.